# iOS- How to create offline operation queue and execute when comes online?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, offline

I have just entry in iOS. I have a scenario : If user's device is offline then add his request (Web services) in a queue with his all request details parameters , and whenever his devices comes online , then hit web services (with data which is already stored) one by one/concurrently until queue empty. I have to use Core data. I am no any idea about this. So, I will be thankful if anyone share link (github/others any site) for sample project. **Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Have you tried? What went wrong? Show your code

Comment: @  Wain, I have no any idea, **I have just entry in iOS**

Answer (score 0):

store data in temp database when offline, when come online check temp data base if there is data then send one by one to server using recursion or for loop which is appropriate.On successfully submission(in completion handler of calling service method) delete that data from temp database and call function from it again if use recursion.

Answer (score 0):

We had similar issues on our internal projects when connectivity spotty, so we wrote this framework that wraps any network request and allows it to be enqueued regardless of connectivity - https://cocoapods.org/pods/OfflineRequestManager. Anybody doing something similar might find it useful or at least draw inspiration from it. You'll still have to manage the network request itself, but it provides a fairly simple interface for ensuring that the app keeps trying to execute it until it succeeds, including saving to disk so it can be reattempted on startup.

The simplest use case would look something like the following, though most actual cases (saving to disk, specific request data, etc.) will have a few more hoops to jump through:

```
import OfflineRequestManager

class SimpleRequest: OfflineRequest {
    func perform(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        doMyNetworkRequest(withCompletion: { response, error in
            handleResponse(response)
            completion(error)
        })
    }
}
///////
OfflineRequestManager.defaultManager(queueRequest: SimpleRequest())
```